# Is it needed to unsubscribe when we don't use rxjs in angular 7

Tags: rxjs, angular7

I am fetching data from api(in service file) and I'm subscribing in ts file.I'm not using rxjs(observable and subscription) .I have confusion regarding whether  it is required to unsubscribe when we don't use rxjs in angular 7.If unsubscribing needed then how can we do that if rxjs is not used

// ts

```
export class ViewDataComponent implements OnInit {

    regions: Region[];
    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<PaginatedMapData>;

    constructor(private ApiServiceObj: ApiService ) {}
    ngOnInit() {

        this.ApiServiceObj.getLocationData().subscribe((res) => {

        this.regions = res;
        console.log(res);
    });

    this.ApiServiceObj.getMarkerDataForTableView(this.startdate, this.enddate, this.regionOption, 0, 10)
      .subscribe((res) => {

            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res['results']);


      });
    }
}
```

Comment: But you *are* using rxjs.

Comment: Yes, you should unsubscribe

Comment: The current "best practice" is to always unsubscribe. As the answer states below, it is not always *required*, but better to always have it.

Answer (score 0):

A Subscription ends when you call the unsubscribe method, but it will also happen automatically when the observable completes or errors:

*An object conforming to the Observer interface is usually given to the observable.subscribe(observer) method, and the Observable will call the Observer's next(value) method to provide notifications. A well-behaved Observable will call an Observer's complete() method exactly once or the Observer's error(err) method exactly once, as the last notification delivered.*

Source:
[http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObserverDoc.html](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js%7EObserverDoc.html)

When this api service you are using is always doing regular http calls, you can be quite sure that those Observables returned will always either immediately enter the completed or error state when the call is done. So actually, you can get away with not unsubscribing in this case. When you are actually starting to use rxjs, and start using subjects etc ... The best practice is to use the "takeUntil" approach to ensure that all subscriptions get cleaned up.

For more info about the takeUntil approach:
https://ncjamieson.com/avoiding-takeuntil-leaks/

Short summary: I personally like using rxjs and reactive programming, but i understand that its not for everybody. Angular does force you to use it when doing http calls. If you and your team take the decision to NOT use rxjs because of its added complexity, then you can get away with not unsubscribing from observables returned from the httpclient.

But you -should- at least understand why it is unnecessary in this case. Simply adding one operator to the observable is enough to introduce leaky subscriptions ...

If you dont want to take my word for it:
https://gitter.im/angular/angular?at=5681e8fa3c68940269251fa5